# Como puedo validar un campo de tipo time con este codigo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

lo que necesito es modificar este script para que tome el valor de un input tipo time del cual debo tomar la hora y validarlo con mysql y mostrarle al usuario una div que diga que esta disponible o que no esta disponible la hora la hora seleccionada

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $.datepicker.setDefaults({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
       });
       $(function(){
            $("#fechax").datepicker("");

       });
       $('#filter').click(function(){
            var fecha = $('#fechax').val();

            if(fecha != '')
            {
                 $.ajax({
                      url:"ajax_ac.php",
                      method:"POST",
                      data:{fecha:fecha},
                      success:function(data)
                      {
                           $('#order_table').html(data);

                      }
                 });
            }
            else
            {
                 alert("Selecciona una fecha");
            }
       });
  });
```

Comment: Hola Pedro, tienes que ofrecer más información en tu pregunta, por ejemplo, cómo está formada tu base de datos y qué significa que este disponible una fecha. Por otro lado, para mejorar el formato de tu pregunta y así aumentar las posibilidades de poder ayudarte, te recomiendo que revises la página de ayuda sobre [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

asi fue como solucione mi problema

`<script>
function validar_hora()
{
var horario = document.getElementById("horario2").value;
var xhr;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
var data = "horario=" + horario;
     xhr.open("POST", "ajax_ac.php", true);
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     xhr.send(data);
     xhr.onreadystatechange = display_data;
    function display_data() {
     if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
       //alert(xhr.responseText);
      document.getElementById("horav").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
      } else {
        alert('Existe un problema con la consulta.');
      }
     }
    }
}
</script>` y la consulta `<?php
 include_once("connect_db.php");
  $horario = $_POST['horario'];
$checkhorario = mysql_query("SELECT horario FROM aireacondicionado WHERE horario='$horario'");
            $horario_exist = mysql_num_rows($checkhorario);
            if ($horario_exist>1)
            {
             echo ' <div class="col-md-4"><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  <strong>Empresa no disponible para la hora seleccionada, por favor ingrese una nueva hora.</strong></div></div>';
              echo '<br/>';
            }else{
              echo '<span class="alert-success">Hora '.$_POST['horario'].' disponible</span><br>
                     <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="horario" value='.$_POST['horario'].' ><br/>
                     <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 100px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>';
            }
?>`